# SQL Select From 2 different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to select data from two tables but I can't figure out the correct way. I got 2 tables - loans and requests.
Loans has fields which are of interest to this particular query e.g status, loan_id. On the other hand, the requests table has some fields too. My query is trying to get data from these 2 tables as such:

```
SELECT a.request_id,
    a.request_date,
    a.customer_id,
    a.request_type,
    a.target_customer,
    a.customer_id,
    a.agent_number,
    a.merchant_number,
    a.bill_reference,
    d.loan_id,
    a.amount
   FROM loans d,
    requests a
    WHERE d.loan_status=12
```

This returns a result with the loan_id field with the same value in each record.
PS: This loan_id column can be null since not all requests are loan applications.

Comment: how will you be joining the two tables?

Comment: You should have some kind of relation between those tables. My guess would be through loan_id?

Comment: OK let me try that...

Comment: This will result in Cartesian product!!. u need join the two tables with related columns

Comment: The relational databases rely on joins between tables (relations). The results you are getting represent a Cartesian product of the two: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a field in the request table (for example loan_id) which references to the loan_id in the loan table. In this case you 'll have to use the following query

```
SELECT a.request_id,
a.request_date,
a.customer_id,
a.request_type,
a.target_customer,
a.customer_id,
a.agent_number,
a.merchant_number,
a.bill_reference,
d.loan_id,
a.amount
 FROM requests a left join  loans d on a.loan_id=d.loan_id
  where d.loan_status=12
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to use Join like

```
SELECT a.request_id,
a.request_date,
a.customer_id,
a.request_type,
a.target_customer,
a.customer_id,
a.agent_number,
a.merchant_number,
a.bill_reference,
d.loan_id,
a.amount
 FROM loans d inner join
requests a
on d.loan_status=12
```

Comment: It definitely needs to be a LEFT join, since not every request has resulted in a loan, as the author described already + the need of a relation between the two, not just d.loan_status=12.